# If I need serializable should i use concrete List (e.g. ArrayList) or (Serializable)List?

Tags: java

We have a discussion in office and cannot understand which approach is better

I have a class (SomeClass) with some method which receives Serializable object. The signature is following:

```
public void someMethod(Serializable serializableObject){
    ...
}
```

And I need to call this method from another class, but I should provide it with some List as fact parameter. There are two different approaches

#### 1. Serializable

```
private SomeClass someClass;

public void doSomething() {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    al.add("text");

    someClass.someMethod((Serializable)al);
}
```

#### 2. ArrayList

```
private SomeClass someClass;

public void doSomething() {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    al.add("text");

    someClass.someMethod(al);
}
```

1. Benefit of the first example is that it adheres to the java’s best practices which says: use interface instead of concrete realization for reference type and any programmer while reading that source will understand that we don't need special behavior of the ArrayList. And the only place we need it's serializable behavior we are adding this behavior by casting  it to the Serializable interface. And programmer can simply change this current realization of the List to some other serializable realization, for example, LinkedList, without any side affect on this element because we use interface List as it`s reference type.
2. Benefit of the second example is that we refer to ArrayList as to class which have not only List behavior but also Serializable behavior. So if someone looked at this code and tried to change ArrayList to List he would receive a compile time error which would reduce time for programmer to understand what is going on there

UPDATE: we can't change someMethod signature. It came from a third-party company and we use it not only for Serializable Lists but also for Strings, Integers and some other Serializable objects

Answer (score 2):

It's better to define `ArrayList` because this combines two interfaces - `List + Serializable`. You need both of them in one place.

It doesn't matter that much, but not that using interfaces should be applied more strictly for return types, and less strictly for local variables.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an interface when all you need is the methods an interface provides. (this is most cases)  However, if you need more than one interface, you can use generics, but the simplest approach is to use the concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the signature of the `someMethod` so that it reflects what it requires from the invoker of the method:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public <T extends List<? extends Serializable> & Serializable> void someMethod(T t) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass test = new SomeClass();
        test.someMethod(new ArrayList<String>());   //Works
        test.someMethod(new ArrayList<Image>());   //Compile time error, Image is not Serializable
        List<String> l = null;
        test.someMethod(l); //Compile time error
    }
}
```

The signature of `someMethod` now says that you must invoke it with something that is a `List`, and that is `Serializable`, and contains elements that are `Serializable`

Comment: It might be a good solution, but we don't have an oportunity to change `SomeClass.someMethod()` signature because this method is provided by the third-party library, and it should accept all kind of Serializable objects, not only Serializable Lists. And our question is just about: which approach will be better when we have such situation when we have to pass an instase of List to such method.

Comment: Ah, ok. Looks like I didn't fully understand your question in that case :) I would use the concrete class in that case.

Comment: The flaw in this approach is that the caller must now provide a serializable list (such as ArrayList), which means that the caller's signature must accept the same type (such as ArrayList).  This could cascade throughout many methods/classes, which would be pretty bad as it unnecessarily constrains the type of List that can be used in these methods.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would just use List, and not worry that the compiler cannot guarantee that your object is serializable (it most likely will be anyway, if you've done things right elsewhere).

Note that methods of the following type (which accept a Serializable parameter) provide a false sense of security, because the compiler can never guarantee that the entire object graph which needs to be serialized will actually be serializable.

```
public void write(Serializable s);
```

Consider an ArrayList (serializable) which contains non-serializable objects.  The signature may as well just be:

```
public void write(Object o);
```

And then you don't have to worry about all the extraneous casting.

Also consider that, although you cannot change the signature of the API you are using, you can very easily create a wrapper API which has a different signature.

Answer (score 0):

1 is generally the right thing to do.  However in this case, my opinion would to be bend that and declare it as ArrayList<>.  This avoids the cast and guarantees that someone can't change the implementation of the List to one that isn't Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do (1) because you're not free to change the List implementation type arbitrarily, which is the whole idea of doing that. You can only use a List implementation that implements Serializable. So you may as well express that in the code.